# How to Trim the Leading and Trailing White-Spaces of a String Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, trim

I want to trim all the white-spaces and empty strings only from the starting and ending of an array without converting it into a string in C#.

This is what I've done so far to solve my problem but I'm looking for a bit more efficient solution as I don't want to be stuck with a just works solution to the prob

```cs
static public string[] Trim(string[] arr)
{
    List<string> TrimmedArray = new List<string>(arr);
    foreach (string i in TrimmedArray.ToArray())
    {
        if (String.IsEmpty(i)) TrimmedArray.RemoveAt(TrimmedArray.IndexOf(i));
        else break;
    }
    
    foreach (string i in TrimmedArray.ToArray().Reverse())
    {
        if (String.IsEmpty(i)) TrimmedArray.RemoveAt(TrimmedArray.IndexOf(i));
        else break;
    }
    
    return TrimmedArray.ToArray();
}
```

NOTE: String.IsEmpty is a custom function which check whether a string was NULL, Empty or just a White-Space.

Comment: Use the loops to test for the first and last occurrence of a _non-empty string_, then record their indexes - then you just need to copy a subset of the original array to a new one and you're done.

Comment: You already have string(s).  Try this : List<string> TrimmedArray = arr.Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();  or Enumerable.Range(start, count).Select(x => arr[x].Trim()).ToList()

Comment: @jdweng I already tried this method but what it does is it trims the strings in the array and what I want is to trim the array itself means remove empty string and white-spaces only from the starting and ending of that array. Similar to the Trim function but for arrays. I think u should try this function by urself then maybe u will get my point. But still thanks for ur effort in answering.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I think it's similar to what jdwend said in his comment. Isn't it?

Comment: No, I understood that it's the array itself you want to truncate - which means you need to find out how many items you need to remove from the start of the array, and how many items you need to remove the end of the array. Find those numbers _first_ (without modifying/removing anything), then copy the relevant remaining parts of the array to a new one with `Array.Copy()` (or a simple loop)

Comment: Do a join and then split removing empty entries : List<string> TrimmedArray = string.Join("^",arr).Split(new char[] { '^' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Ya, I think perhaps this solution will work. Thanks for ur help :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'll be really happy if u can also explain me the flaws in my code.

Comment: Why did you write a custom function to determine if a string is null, empty or whitespace when [`string.IsNullOrWhitespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-6.0) already exists?

Comment: @Wyck I wrote a custom function because it check for both `string.IsNullOfWhitespace` and `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

Comment: `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("")` returns true.  So you should be fine.

Comment: @Wyck Nope in my case I require both so I made a function.

Comment: @Light-Lens I'd love to know which cases you think won't be handled correctly by `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` alone, please.

Comment: @Wyck I want to exclude both empty and whitespace strings in that Trim function I asked in my question.

Comment: @Light-Lens, If I understand correctly, you want a function that returns true if the value is `null` or `System.String.Empty` (i.e. `""`) or if the value consists exclusively of white-space characters.  Is that right?

Comment: @Wyck Yes, it's right. That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: Perfect. You should read the documentation for [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-6.0). I'll quote it here for you.  _true if the value parameter is null or System.String.Empty, or if value consists exclusively of white-space characters._.

Comment: @Wyck Means it's what can fulfil what I want without any extra code. Right? That's Great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code allocates *a lot* of new arrays unnecessarily. When you instantiate a list from an array, the list creates a new backing array to store the items, and every time you call `ToArray()` on the resulting list, you're also allocating yet another copy.

The second problem is with `TrimmedArray.RemoveAt(TrimmedArray.IndexOf(i))` - if the array contains multiple copies of the same string value in the middle as at the end, you might end up removing strings from the middle.

My advice would be split the problem into two distinct steps:

- Find both boundary indices (the first and last *non-empty* strings in the array)
- Copy only the relevant middle-section to a new array.

To locate the boundary indices you can use [`Array.FindIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex) and [`Array.FindLastIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findlastindex):

```
static public string[] Trim(string[] arr)
{
    if(arr == null || arr.Length == 0)
        // no need to search through nothing
        return Array.Empty<string>();

    // define predicate to test for non-empty strings
    Predicate<string> IsNotEmpty = string s => !String.IsEmpty(str);

    var firstIndex = Array.FindIndex(arr, IsNotEmpty);

    if(firstIndex < 0)
        // nothing to return if it's all whitespace anyway
        return Array.Empty<string>();

    var lastIndex = Array.FindLastIndex(arr, IsNotEmpty);

    // calculate size of the relevant middle-section from the indices
    var newArraySize = lastIndex - firstIndex + 1;

    // create new array and copy items to it
    var results = new string[newArraySize];
    Array.Copy(arr, firstIndex, results, 0, newArraySize);

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer by Mathias R. Jessen as it is efficient and clean.

Just thought I'd show how to do it using the `List<>` as in your original attempt:

```
static public string[] Trim(string[] arr)
{
    List<string> TrimmedArray = new List<string>(arr);
    while (TrimmedArray.Count>0 && String.IsEmpty(TrimmedArray[0]))
    {
        TrimmedArray.RemoveAt(0);            
    }
    while (TrimmedArray.Count>0 && String.IsEmpty(TrimmedArray[TrimmedArray.Count - 1]))
    {
        TrimmedArray.RemoveAt(TrimmedArray.Count - 1);
    }
    return TrimmedArray.ToArray();
}
```

This is not as efficient as the other answer since the internal array within the `List<>` has to shift all its elements to the left each time an element is deleted from the front.